# C# trying to isolate name from html using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, title

```
<a href="||blablabla link||" title="||blablabla title of torrent|| torrent">||THE STRING THAT IM INTERESTED IN--NAMES||</a>
```

im working on an html file that contains 20-30 of the above format lines ! Im interested in saving all of the NAMES in an array list. My problem is that i cant quite understand regex format to get each NAMES
what pattern should i use ? How do i use this pattern to capture every name in this html string ?
thank you !

Comment: You need to show more format,because `blablabla` was useless,is there any other dom `a` in html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string html = @"<a href=""/torrent/4353486/Terminator+Genisys+2015+720p+WEBRip+%5BChattChitto+RG%5D.‌​html"" title=""view Terminator Genisys 2015 720p WEBRip [ChattChitto RG] torrent"">Terminator Genisys 2015 720p WEBRip [ChattChitto RG]</a>";
string patten = @"<a\s+href=""[^""]*""\s+title=""[^""]*torrent"".*?>([^<]*)</a>";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(html, patten, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This is an example,I guess your dom's title must be end with `torrent`